# How to get current moment Activity status in portrait or landscape, not the orientation setting

Tags: android, android-fragments

I write a fragment. By it's UI, it only good when activity is current in portrait (or reversed) status.

I know activity can be set as:

1. portrait or reverse portrait mode
2. user mode or sensor mode
3. un-specified mode.

All of above setting may lead to a portrait status in some case.

I want do:

1. check if activity is current in portrait status, but not care if it's portrait mode or user mode or un-specified mode, also no care if the device is rotated or not. I just care the activity status in just the current moment, because of the UI.
2. if current is portrait, than save activity orientation setting, and set it as lock setting(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED).
3. show the fragment UI, and user close it.
4. restore activity orientation setting.

Now I can do step 2/3/4, but I don't how to do step 1.

I have read a lot of post in stackoverflow, but most of posts are about orientation setting, not the current moment status.

I had know how to check rotation in activity or in fragment such as onConfigurationChanged. But I hope check first, and then run my fragment. I also hope not insert code in activity to monitor rotation.

Please tell me how to do step 1. Thanks.

==================================

So sorry to post such a stupid question. It's very simple --- just check content view's height and width.

```
public boolean isPortraitStatus(Activity activity){

    View contentView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    int height = contentView.getHeight();
    int width = contentView.getWidth();

    if (height > width){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

if I should delete this post?

Comment: What is wrong with `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`?

Comment: @kalabalik which is setting, not status

Comment: You mean setter, not getter? No, it can be both.

Comment: @kalabalik I mean current UI orientation, such as if toolbar at shorter or longer edge.

Comment: @kalabalik If setting is SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED, the toolbar can at both edge, depending on device setting and rotation.